# Which test(s) for analyzing yes-no answers for control vs treated conditions

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

To keep it simple, I have sets of data in which I have a control and a treated sample. The data I obtain is "yes" or "no" (0 or 1) for a particular behaviour. I have 150 data points for each condition (150 for control, 150 treated), obtained across 3 experimental runs, which I intend to pool. They are not paired in any way.

Which test would you recommend? I am currently thinking that binary logistic regression is the best choice, but I'm not sure. I am a biologist and not a mathematician, so please keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

A binary logistic regression would work, for the same reason that you can use a regression when you want to compare two sample means.

However, it may be more apparatus that is required.

With a small sample, one might consider a [binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test). In this case, your sample sizes are nice and big, so a straight out proportions test should be effectively indistinguishable from it and a little simpler to deal with.

However, since you have three experimental runs it might be worth including experimental run as a covariate (even though if all is well it should not have a covariate effect). In that case, you *could* use logistic regression to do teh comparison incorporating the experimental run variable, or you could look at a chi-square test to achieve basically the same thing (though if you want a one-tailed test, the first thing would be better).

Answer (score 0):

Since your metric is a proportion, the hypothesis test for proportions is the best choice.

This [pdf](http://www2.latech.edu/~schroder/slides/stat/hyptest_prop.pdf) can help you

Comment: The conclusion may be correct, but the logic is not: one does not select statistical tests based on the data type.

Comment: Certainly the general category of model/test is determined by what the question of interest is, but I think data type definitely comes into it -- after all, if the data were not proportions or counts, one wouldn't even *consider* a proportions test. The data type, therefore, must be at least part of the basis on which such selections are made.

Comment: @Glen_b Agreed.  What I was objecting to was the "logic:" namely, concluding that the data type determines the "best choice" of procedure.

Comment: No dispute there. Indeed if I was reading this for the first time now, I'd probably have just assumed that was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

A proportion test as zeferino suggest, or also a $\chi^2$ test or the Fisher exact probability test.

Comment: Which one would you recommend? Each comes with its own null hypothesis, and the sampling design suggests that at least one margin if fixed in the two-way table.

Comment: I think that with enough number of data the p-values are very similar in any case. With few data, it is clear that a Chi square must be avoided. (or use the Yates correction, but probably is better a Fisher test).

Comment: Thanks to you and Zeferino. I will look at the recommended tests and see if one will work best.